# Using the value of the last row of a column as a range?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a vba code that determines the date based on 3 cells in excel, it then reformats the date.

```
Sub Test()

Dim i As Long
i = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

Range("K3").Formula = "=DATE(A3,G3,H3)"
Range("K3").AutoFill Destination:=Range("K3:K28")

Set fmt = Range("K3:K28")
fmt.NumberFormat = "ddmmmyyyy"

End Sub
```

The line that gives a value to "i" (which is 28) determines the last populated cell in that column.
I would like to use the value of "i" as K28 in the range.

I am fairly new to VBA and have not been able to figure out how to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can slightly simplify your code. There is no need to use `AutoFill`:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim i As Long
    With Sheet1
        i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        With .Range("K3:K" & i)
            .Formula = "=DATE(A3,G3,H3)"
            .NumberFormat = "ddmmmyyyy"
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```